# Multiple messy tables

Tags: r, import, xls, reshape

I have multiple xls files automatically generated.The format of each file is like this:

```
StartTableCommonCode  
Code 1  
Code 1.1  
Header1 Header2
1  a
2  b
3  c
4  d

StartTableCommonCode
Code 2  
Code 2.1  
Header1 Header2
5 e
6 f
7 g
8 h
```

and, each files contains multiple tables.

I would like to obtain something like (without using other external softwares):

```
HeaderA HeaderB Header1 Header2
Code 1  Code 1.1  1 a
Code 1  Code 1.1  2 b
Code 1  Code 1.1  3 c
Code 1  Code 1.1  4 d
Code 2  Code 2.1  5 e
Code 2  Code 2.1  6 f
Code 2  Code 2.1  7 g
Code 2  Code 2.1  8 h
```

Comment: What have you already tried yourself?

Comment: This is one of three types of files that have to be imported.
For others it has been sufficient few lines of code to edit and organize.
Honestly I have no idea how to approach this problem ...

Comment: This seems pretty well-structured, so it shouldn't be too difficult (though it would be even easier if you weren't dealing with xls files). Or are your tables even more messy than you describe here?

Comment: The input file is a bit 'more complex than that.
But the structure is "enough" regular. In the various tables (like 10/20 for each file) there are 'totals' and white lines that i can  easily eliminate.
What escapes me is how to "move" the lines that contain the code for the table.

Comment: However, the import does not cause me problems, the only problem is the structure.

Comment: I have not yet a solution but this package just released can be helpful: https://github.com/rsheets/jailbreakr